# When is it good to avoid Join in Rethinkdb

Tags: join, rethinkdb

Let's say we have two tables: `user` and `comment`. Each comment has a foreign key to user and a one thread id. Thread id is not unique.
We want to fetch all comments by thread id with associated users. We know that there are only a couple of unique users associated to that comment set (example: 1000 comments :-: 10 users).

I have two strategies to do a query:

1. using equal join:

   ```
   r.db('test').table('comments').get_all(thread_id, index='t')\  
   .eq_join('user', r.db('test').table('user'))
   ```
2. using two separate queries:

   ```
   comments = list(r.db('test').table('comments').get_all(thread_id, index='t').run())
   user_ids = set([c['user'] for c in comments])
   users = list(r.db('test').table('user').get_all(*users))
   ```

**Which one is the preffered one?** Or maybe there is other better solution?

When doing some tests I found that 2. has better performance - which is reasonable. We don't need to link on DB side all the same users and a transferred data is smaller.

How it conforms with RethinkDB design and how RethinkDB goes for joins? If RethinkDB has joins then I assume some usage is justified (eg when a number of comments has the same order as the number of associated users).

Comment: You should definitely be specifying an index in your `eq_join`

Comment: there is default `index='id'` in `eq_join` function

Comment: Hi Robert,
both of these queries should behave very similarly as far as scalability is concerned.
`eq_join` in RethinkDB is actually implemented very similarly to what you are doing in your query. It just performs a `get_all` on the right hand table for each of the documents in the left hand sequence.

May I ask how big the performance difference is that you saw? It's possible that the get_all variant is slightly better optimized in our current implementation than eq_join.

Comment: I was testing it on 1.13; results: 1) ~1.5sec; 2) ~2sec